# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Default WL.StaticAppProps values

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-runtime

By default in the latest IBM Worklight 6.0 driver it seems the StaticAppProps object is set to:

```
WL.StaticAppProps = {
"APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "defaultTestApp",
"APP_SERVICES_URL": "\/apps\/services\/",
"APP_VERSION": "1.0",
"ENVIRONMENT": "android",
"LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE": "embedded",
"WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "6.0.0",
"WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL": "\/apps\/services\/api\/defaultTestApp\/android\/"
};'
```

There is another property named "APP_ID" and I was wondering a few things:

Why isn't that a default property added to the object? (in a previous version I thought this was by default)

Since the ID is set for the display name by default, is this name used somewhere directly out of box within the app?

Should I expect someone to set the APP_DISPLAY_NAME to something like "My Banking App" or should I always keep the APP_DISPLAY_NAME as the app id?

In general, is the best practice to keep the StaticAppProps object synced with the values used in application-descriptor.xml?

Comment: if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

1. IMO there is no reason for you to touch (alter) those static properties...
2. The app id is used mostly internally at the moment when creating mobile environments and in other locations within
3. To change the external name of the app (what you see under the app icon in the device), you change the `displayName` property in application-descriptor.xml

By default the app name is the same as the id (the value you enter when creating a new Worklight application), but you can change it as described in 3 above.